# joomla - menu items - category blog

Tags: joomla

Is there a way to add a menu item after all the articles in a Category Blog menu item?

So I have a menu item that is a category blog and it is showing articles but I want to have a menu item after all/any of the articles.

eg: Events/Event-A/Register (Events is a category blog, event-a is an article and register is the page to register for the event)

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: Is that menuitem always the same ? or it depends on the event-X ?

Comment: Just curious: wouldn't be easier to use an events extension ?

Comment: It might be but I am interested in this problem right now because it doesn't just pertain to 'events'.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't do that out if the box.

Here are your options:

1. Build a custom component.
2. Use an existing component that does the job.
3. Add the links manually to each event page.
4. Build a plugin that will add a dynamic link to your event page.

Your question is a little vague, are you struggling with adding menu items, or are you struggling with adding the third page in your article hierarchy? Or are you struggling to add a link/button that appears at the bottom of an event page?

Comment: Thanks for this reply your option of 3 is what I have done to get the job done. Your option of 4 will be what I will attempt next week as per your reply to my other thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780857/bypass-joomla-menu-system/9793455#9793455